# Laravel join query on two tables with conditional table name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, query-builder

how to provide table name as a column value in join laravel, i have two table (name as) fabric and (name as) conversion name and this value is value is store in third table name as payments
and my query is

```
DB::table('payments')->where('payment_id')->get()
```

this query will provide data like that

```
[
 {
    "payment_date": "2020-07-10",
    "payment_amount": 20,
    "payment_method": "check",
    "payment_option": "receive",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "contract_type": "fabric",//here will be two value 'fabric' or 'conversion'
 },
 {
    "payment_date": "2020-07-10",
    "payment_amount": 20,
    "payment_method": "check",
    "payment_option": "receive",
    "contract_id": 1,
    "contract_type": "conversion",
 },
 {
     "payment_date": "2020-07-10",
     "payment_amount": 20,
     "payment_method": "check",
     "payment_option": "receive",
     "contract_id": 1,
     "contract_type": "fabric",
 },
]
```

'fabric' and 'conversion' are the table names and my idea is like this

```
DB::table('payments')->where('payment_id')
->join('{$payments.contract_type}','payments.contract_id','=','{$payments.contract_type}.id')
->select('payments.*','{$payments.contract_type}.contract_no')
->get();
```

but its not working
above in second query `'{$payments.contract_type}'` try to getting the contract_type(column name) value getting from payments table its the table name

Note:: whole idea behind it to include contract_no in objects from 'conversion' or 'fabric' table

Comment: You might want to take a look at [polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Eloquent to be able to do a polymorphic relation :

In your Payment model :

```
public function contract(){
      return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In your Fabric AND Conversion Models :

```
public function payment()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Payment::class, 'contract');
}
```

Then

```
$payments = Payment::with('contract')->get();

foreach($payments as $payment){
    $contract = $payment->contract;
}
```

if you can, you should change the contract_type from fabric to `Fabric::class` and conversion to `Conversion::class` if you cannot do that, then in your AppServiceProvider :

```
Relation::morphMap([
            'conversion' => Conversion::class,
            'fabric'  => Fabric::class,
        ]);
```